# How to Substitute "Dummy" values to std::cin?

Tags: c++, iostream, cin

Given the simple program below:

```
int main() {
    int v;
    std::vector<int> values;
    while(std::cin >> v) {
        values.emplace_back(v);
    }
    std::cout << "The Sum is " << std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to fill up `std::cin` programmatically before this code executes, in a similar manner to the following:

```
int main() {
    int v;
    std::vector<int> values;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cin << i << " "; //Doesn't compile, obviously
    }
    /*
    The Rest of the Code.
    */
    return 0;
}
```

But of course, that code does not work. Is there something I could do which would allow me to "pipe" data into `std::cin` *without manually piping in data from a different program or from the command line shell* like `echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" | myprogram.exe` would?

Comment: If possible for you, changing `std::cin` to a `std::istringstream` object works. Instead of functions using `std::cin` directly, they would have a `std::istream&` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the `rdbuf` associated with `std::cin` to pull that off.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
   int v;
   std::vector<int> values;

   // Create a istringstream using a hard coded string.
   std::string data = "10 15 20";
   std::istringstream str(data);

   // Use the rdbuf of the istringstream as the rdbuf of std::cin.
   auto old = std::cin.rdbuf(str.rdbuf());

   while(std::cin >> v) {
      values.emplace_back(v);
   }
   std::cout << "The Sum is " << std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0) << std::endl;

   // Restore the rdbuf of std::cin.
   std::cin.rdbuf(old);

   return 0;
}
```

See it working at http://ideone.com/ZF02op.